# Async function in a promise callback

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to do something like this but it's breaking:

```
myAsyncFunction = async () => {
    fetchResource().then( res => {
        await fetchAnotherResource()
        ....
    })
}
```

Within the completion of the first promise, I want to use await expressions, but it doesn't look like the scope of that callback allows for async functions.

With the way it is above, it tells me that await is a reserved keyword (it's not picking up any meaning for await in this case, because of scope I'm guessing?)

If I declare the anonymous function with `async` like this:

```
fetchResource().then( async (res) => {...})
```

I get a syntax error like this:

```
ProductForm.jsx?130a:143 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _context.t1) is not a function
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this is inside of a React component.

Is there a syntax for accomplishing what I'm trying to do here? (Use an async function as a promise handler)

**Edit: relevant code** (sorry for code dump)

```
initializeState = async () => {
    getShopInfo(this.state.shop_id)
    .then (async (res) => {
        if (product_id) {
            ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeEditState(product_id, defaultLocalization, localizations))
        } else {
            ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeBlankState(defaultLocalization, localizations))
        }
    })
}

initializeEditState = (product_id, defaultLocalization, localizations, allCategoriesPromises) => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        let productPromiseArray = []; // storage for auxiliary localization requests
        let filledOutLocalizations = []; // hold localizations that have been merged with the product data 
        getProduct(product_id, defaultLocalization.localization_id)
        .then( json => {
            /* fetch object that will represent a product in state 
            * and merge it with the default localization object */
            let defaultProductState = this.setupEditProductState(json)
            defaultLocalization = Object.assign(defaultLocalization, defaultProductState)

            /* setup promise array for all other localizations */
            localizations.forEach( l => {
                productPromiseArray.push(getProduct(product_id, l.localization_id)) 
            })

            /* fetch other products and merge them with localizations */
            Promise.all( productPromiseArray )
            .then( resultArray => {
                resultArray.forEach( res => {
                    /* test for fail condition here;
                    * fail condition happens when new localizations 
                    * are registered between edits */
                    let loc = localizations.find( 
                        l => l.localization_id ==  res.data.product.localization_id
                    )
                    if (res.result) {
                        loc = Object.assign(loc, this.setupEditProductState(res))
                    } else {
                        /* Default state for this localization 
                        * (you should have access to defaultLocalization) */
                        loc = Object.assign(defaultProductState, loc)
                    }
                    filledOutLocalizations.push(loc)
                }) 
                /* Finally, get ALL category lists and
                    * INITIALIZE EDIT STATE */
                let promiseArray = []
                for (var filLoc of filledOutLocalizations) {
                    promiseArray.push(getAllCategories(filLoc.localization_id))
                }

                resolve({ activeLocalization: defaultLocalization, localizations: filledOutLocalizations })
            })
        })
    })
}

initializeBlankState = ( defaultLocalization, localizations ) => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        let activeLocalization = Object.assign( 
            defaultLocalization, 
            this.getBlankState(defaultLocalization.localization_id)
        )
        activeLocalization.product.enable_flg = 1
        localizations = localizations.map( l => {
            return Object.assign(l, this.getBlankState(l.localization_id))
        })
        resolve({ activeLocalization, localizations })
    })
}
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error, that's a runtime error. Can you post the fuller code so that the problem is reproducible?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see, yep sorry; kind of a mess

Comment: Out of interest, why are you mixing promises/await? Why not just await `getShopInfo`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yeah I am realizing that would probably be a better tactic; I guess it's just because I am refactoring old code and being lazy. Do you think the two styles conflict with each other?

Comment: No,I don't think there's anything preventing it, though I think in general it's "easier" to use await/async if you have it available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not work in your original version because `await` can only be used inside an `async` function. The function inside `then` has its own scope, which does not relate to the outer one anymore; thus using `await` there is invalid.

The second version, in which you put `async` inside `then` is a violation of return type. From [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) of `Promise.prototype.then`:

> The then() method returns a Promise

and [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) of `async function`:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which
>   returns an AsyncFunction object

you can see that those two should not be used together.

Normally, `async-await` is used to replace `Promise - then - catch`, not for using together. So for your sample function, it should be:

```
myAsyncFunction = async () => {
    const resource = await fetchResource();
    if (isValidResource(resource)) {
        const anotherResource = await fetchAnotherResource();
        ...
    }
}
```

And for your function `initializeState`, which uses `async`:

```
initializeState = async () => {
    const res = await getShopInfo(this.state.shop_id);
    if (product_id) {
        ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeEditState(product_id, defaultLocalization, localizations))
    } else {
        ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeBlankState(defaultLocalization, localizations))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view `async` inside `then(..)` is redundant in your case. Just continue use Promises.In `fetchResource().then( res => fetchAnotherResource()).then(res=>{code...})` last code will wait completion of `fetchAnotherResource(..)`. 
So, your code

```
.then (async (res) => {
    if (product_id) {
        ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeEditState(product_id, defaultLocalization, localizations))
    } else {
        ({ activeLocalization, localizations } = await this.initializeBlankState(defaultLocalization, localizations))
    }
})
```

can be rewrite like

```
.then ((res) => product_id?
                 this.initializeEditState(product_id, defaultLocalization, localizations)):
                 this.initializeBlankState(defaultLocalization, localizations))
)
.then(({activeLocalization,localizations})=>{.....})
```